# How to Resolve GCC's Confusion with Standard Library Include Paths

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I wrote a C++ library which builds fine (gcc 4.6.3), until I tried linking with openssl. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Using  `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`  the openssl includes are installed in `/usr/include/openssl`.   But using `-I /usr/include` causes dozens of errors with the C++ libraries. They appear to be using `/usr/local/include/` and this new include path is causing conflicts.

I see that versions of the C++ libraries are in both

```
    /usr/include/
    /usr/local/include/
```

with the version in `/usr/include` more up-to-date.

How can I direct gcc to to use `/usr/include/c++` for standard libraries? And would that be the correct way to solve my problem?

Comment: There must be something odd with your setup because `/usr/include` is usually included by default.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: hmmm, this is embarrassing. It turns out my make file was set to use arm-linux-gcc instead of gcc... Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to mess with `-I` flags. Headers can be included with

```
#include <openssl/[header name here]>
```

Libraries can be linked in using `-l<library name>`. For example, you would link `libssl` with:

```
g++ <other options> -lssl <files>
```

Comment: `-I` flags are used all the time. It is quite common to not install libraries in the default include search path.

Comment: @DavidBrown I've never run across this. At any rate, it isn't the case here. The Ubuntu packages just install in the usual `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`

Comment: I do use `#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>`, but unless I have an `-I /usr/include` it won't find the files.

Comment: ah, so if my setup was normal, then I wouldn't need the `-I`, because it'd already be looking into `/usr/include/`.

Comment: @jensph Then there's something very odd with your Ubuntu installation, it's not supposed to be like that. Can you verify that you're using the stock gcc/g++ compiler, and not some other gcc binary that is installed somwhere else (gcc is supposed to be in /usr/bin )

Comment: You are right: once I used the right compiler, I successfully removed the `-I`.